# ROI package doesn't give a solution (qpoases solver) for an unconstrained QP

Tags: r, optimization, quadratic-programming, quadprog, r-optimization

I'm setting up a simple QP to test the ROI R package. However, the package isn't able to give a wrong solution to a simple toy problem when it is unconstrained.

Example,

```
# Maximize -1/2 x^2 + x, no constraints
> x <- OP(Q_objective(as.matrix(-1), 1), maximum = TRUE, bounds = V_bound(lb = -Inf, ub = Inf, nobj = 1))
> x
> ROI Optimization Problem:

  Maximize a quadratic objective function of length 1 with
  - 1 continuous objective variable,

  subject to
  - 0 constraints
  - 1 lower and 0 upper non-standard variable bounds.
```

Looks good. But when I solve the problem I get,

```
> sol <- ROI_solve(x, solver = 'qpoases')
> sol
  No optimal solution found.
  The solver message was: Initialisation failed! QP could not be solved!
  The objective value is: 0.000000e+00
> sol$solution
  [1] 0
> sol$objval
  [1] 0
> sol$status
  $code
  [1] 1

  $msg
   solver qpoases
    code 36
   symbol RET_INIT_FAILED_HOTSTART
   message Initialisation failed! QP could not be solved!
   roi_code 1
```

Thats odd. On a related note, when I use the quadprog solver, I'm able to get the unconstrained solution (= 1), however I've had to switch from using quadprog to qpoases for other reasons.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

Oddly enough this works,

```
> ROI_solve(OP(Q_objective(as.matrix(-1), 1), maximum = TRUE), solver = 'qpoases')
  No optimal solution found.
  The solver message was: Initialisation failed! QP could not be solved!
  The objective value is: 0.000000e+00
> ROI_solve(OP(Q_objective(as.matrix(1), -1), maximum = FALSE), solver = 'qpoases')
  Optimal solution found.
  The objective value is: -5.000000e-01
```

Comment: Seems like this should be addressed to the package maintainer (after making sure that typical mistakes like initial values outside the feasible domain are not present in you specification.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This different results result from a different value set in the parameter `hessian_type` if the argument `hessian_type` is not provided by the
user ROI.plugin.qpoases chooses the `hessian_type`. And due to a
bug in the choosing of the hessian type for the first example it choose 
for the first example the `hessian_type = 6` (unknown) and for the second
the correct `hessian_type = 1` identity.

```
x1 <- OP(Q_objective(as.matrix(-1), 1), maximum = TRUE, bounds = NULL)
s1 <- ROI_solve(x1, solver = 'qpoases', hessian_type = 1L)
solution(s1)

x1 <- OP(Q_objective(as.matrix(-1), 1), maximum = TRUE, bounds = NULL)
s1 <- ROI_solve(x1, solver = 'qpoases', hessian_type = 6L)
solution(s1)
```

This is fixed in the new version and the new version is on the way to CRAN.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @Florian